# Getting null when decoding what it seems to be a JSON object

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

In the Firebug when a AJAX call is sent I see the response as JSON

[image]
[image]

I'm trying to decode this JSON response with PHP

```
$data = '[[10592,[[2778318,"Damash Gilan FC","Malavan",10592,"2013-12-06T11:30:00.0000000",[[5950609,0,,,,1]],[],,,,,5732,5717,-1,-1,0,0,0,0,"Soccer","Iran - Pro League",1],[2778319,"Gostaresh Foolad","Teraktor Sazi",10592,"2013-12-06T11:30:00.0000000",[[5950610,0,,,,1]],[],,,,,0,8111,-1,-1,0,0,0,0,"Soccer","Iran - Pro League",1],[2778320,"Saba Battery","Naft Tehran",10592,"2013-12-06T11:30:00.0000000",[[5950611,0,,,,1]],[],,,,,5718,10035,-1,-1,0,0,0,0,"Soccer","Iran - Pro League",1],[2778321,"Esteghlal Khuzestan","Mes Kerman",10592,"2013-12-06T11:30:00.0000000",[[5950612,0,,,,1]],[],,,,,0,5727,-1,-1,0,0,0,0,"Soccer","Iran - Pro League",1],[2778324,"Piroozi Perspolis","Zob Ahan",10592,"2013-12-06T12:50:00.0000000",[[5950615,0,,,,1]],[],,,,,5715,5723,-1,-1,0,0,0,0,"Soccer","Iran - Pro League",1]],0]]';

var_dump(json_decode($data , true ));
```

But I keep getting `null` as result

`json_last_error` is returning 4 which apparently means null

Comment: the *"json"* doesn't seem to be valid. `,,,,` in particular isn't valid.

Comment: It's definitely invalid json

Comment: @KevinB but firebug seem to think it's a valid json , it shows in the json tab

Comment: it's a false positive. try it here: http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: All key values should be double quoted. All null values should be specified as `null`. http://jsonviewer.stack.hu is another good place to visualise your JSON (but it's not a validator). Also, don't forget that parsers in different languages can be more or less forgiving of mistakes - just make sure it's valid and you'll be okay everywhere